# C# : How do I get a count of and group the results into unique items from a nested list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying/searching for 2 days now. I have this object type.

```
    public class QCProcessDetail
    {
        public DateTime CreatedDateUTC { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompletedDateUTC { get; set; }
        public string CompletedByUser { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class QCProcessStages
    {
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public ICollection<QCProcessDetail> QCProcessDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to get a count of unique "createdByUsers". I can obtain the usernames using various examples I have seen from here but the results come out as

```
CreateByUserX = 1;
CreatedByUserY = 1;
CreatedByUserX = 1; ...
```

I need a result like this

```
CreatedByUserX = 2
CreateByUserY = 1
```

Comment: Please, provide examples: original data and your code.

Comment: What you have tried to produce that **wrong** result with your **right** data?

Comment: @Dimitry : Orignal code for your reference, I just wanted to make it kind of universal for others to uderstand the structure.

Comment: @Tanmay : I have tried so many suggestions from this site mainly, but the results never came out as I needed. I suppose because I couldn't find an example that had my data structure as is

Comment: That isn't a JSON object.

Comment: `var uniqueCount = QCProcessDetails.Select(x=>x.CreatedByUser).Distinct()` ?

Comment: @Darren : Sorry my bad, deserialized already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer accordingly for your updated example data:

```
stages
    .SelectMany(s => s.QCProcessDetails)
    .GroupBy(d => d.CreatedByUser)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine(g.Key + " = " + g.Count()));
```

Comment: Yes, I have now edited to include my original data structure. I retrieve the information from a server which is deserialized. I unpack the data and display the relevant information in a grid but now I want to include some stats and hence the number of times the "Createdbyuser" comes in handy

Comment: @jeranio I just updated my answer for your new data example.

Comment: Wow..I really need to study this.Your solution worked exactly as I wanted. I am going to study your solution and play around more with LINQ. Seems like I deal with a lot of data. Thanks again, you a star